# Protractor: How to correcly set an expectation getText() of each function?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I’m testing a page with filtered products by title, and want to set an expectation about the correctness of the test: that all titles on the page consist a WORD «Juvederm», NOT any other titles («Emla», «Coolsense» etc.)). 
And should ONLY find the title by the first word - Juvederm (not the Full title: JUVEDERM® ULTRA SMILE Europe; JUVEDERM® VOLBELLA WITH LIDOCAINE Europe).

Html of one product is:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 block_history_" style="">
<section class="product">
    <div class="product__holder">
        <a href="https://www.cosmedicalsupplies.com/.html" class="product__category"></a>
        <h2 class="product__title">
            <a href="juvederm-hydrate.html">JUVEDERM® HYDRATE™ Europe</a>
        </h2>
    </div>
</section>
```

My code console.log(s) correctly (if "Juvederm" is available on the page - it shows "Passed", if not - "NOT PASSED":

```
it("products titles on the page should be Juvederm", () => { 
let product = $$(".product > div > h2 > a");

    browser.get(«…/advanced_search.html?keyword=juvederm");  

    product.each(function(element, index) {
        element.getText().then(function(text) {
            if(text.indexOf("JUVEDERM®") !== -1) {
                    console.log(«Passed»);
            }else{
                    console.log("NOT PASSED");
            }
       }); 
    }); 
});
```

But I decided for myself that I need to have an expectation. 
How/Where to set it? And what expectation must be? When I use in "If"

```
expect(order.product.getText()).toEqual(text);
```

I get an error about differences of texts:

```
JUVEDERM® HYDRATE™ Europe toEqual JUVEDERM®
```

When I used in "If"

```
browser.wait(() => {
    return EC.textToBePresentInElement(order.product);
    }, 3000, "ASDF");
```

test Passed (but I need to see "JUVEDERM®", not "ASDF").

Please, advice smth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change expect statement like below.

```
expect(order.product.getText()).toContain('JUVEDERM®');
```

Comment: I have an error: Expected [ 'JUVEDERM® HYDRATE™ Europe', 'JUVEDERM® ULTRA 2 Europe' ] to contain 'JUVEDERM®'.

Comment: Oh, sorry. In my case I should use element parameter: expect(element.getText()).toContain("JUVEDERM®");

Answer (score 1):

Use `toContain()` to check including substring or not.

```
it("products titles on the page should be Juvederm", () => {
    let products = $$(".product .product__title > a");

    browser.get("advanced_search.html?keyword=juvederm");  

    products.each(product => {
        expect(product.getText()).toContain('JUVEDERM®');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: In my case I should use element parameter: expect(element.getText()).toContain("JUVEDERM®");
Thanks for the answer.